# How to clear all memory and variable every new run in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Python 3.8. I have a file test.py. If I change any code in it then it shows output as it’s previous code. I think it recalls the previous memory. How to get rid of it ? I think I have to clear all memory before every Run. I restarted the computer but couldn’t solve this problem.

Comment: How are you running this file?

Comment: Seems a little weird but you can try delete the __pycache__ directories inside the project maybe

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spyder IDE, you may choose "Preferences" in "Tools" columns, then click on the "Remove all variables before execution" in "Run".

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code